# Convert Unique ID from timestamp and email address

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have created a unique ID for new rows using TRIM, TEXTJOIN and converting the timestamp into Milliseconds.

How can I compact the formula so generates on new rows only and eliminates the need for B and D

Here is the Google Sheet showing the current setup and desired structure, replace copy at the end instead of edit if you want to make a copy
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gYut_iiTycVWfJ29Cc1hdXG7Iu69kPCLxEn9aHJ7_RI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for another way for this to be done in JavaScript? If so you could do something like follows

`staticText.substring(0, 2) + new Date().getTime();`

So for example `"harry@example.com."substring(0, 2) + new Date().getTime();` will return "ha1526467320333".

If its via Google Sheets then you can use a formula similar to the following which will give you the unique ID in one go.

`CONCAT(left(StaticText, 2), text(A3 * 86400000,"#"))`

Let me know if that's kind of what you had in mind.